# Formal way of writing a logger in Play framework

Tags: scala, logging, playframework, websocket, akka

I am new to Play framework and using play 2.5.3 . I need to have logging in my code. Currently for my application , am just creating a Logger object for each class and writing it as similar to how i write comments inside code (just being a bit more informative with logger) like :- before functional blocks and inside blocks or before return statements , etc.
for example: - in my HomeController.scala

```
val homelogger: Logger = Logger(this.getClass()) 

 homelogger.info("creating postActor having props of ChatActor class")

 homelogger.info("passing the actors out and postActor to MyWebSocketActor class")

 homelogger.info("Establishing connection with a new client")
```

My questions are : -

1.) Is this correct way of writing logger for companies' work? or should i be more or less specific or follow some norms here?

2.) I am passing direct strings in homelogger.info() block. Is it standard way for Play based applications or i can define some strings and pass it as object to that block ? in the latter case , how?

**Note** :- 
I am writing application using Akka based WebSockets. So for iddentifying unique connections in log, i am also printing actor-reference to that connection. Suggest the other way if that is not good.

Comment: It is always better to have your messages in an external file. So you won't have to recompile your code if you decide to change it.